# Tunnelling AMQP over HTTP?

Tags: python, http, amqp

Are there any standard libraries or packages (preferably python-oriented) for providing HTTP gateways to AMQP-based applications?

For e.g. I have a an application which uses AMQP for communication between hosts, and would like a migration path for situations where the network may not permit traffic other than HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMQP is a TCP-based protocol, so if you take some TCP proxy code like [this Activestate recipe for Python](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502293-hex-dump-port-forwarding-network-proxy-server/), and modify it to forward data over port 80, then that will probably do it.

However if you have to go througa firewall that looks at the packets and recognizes the HTTP protocol, you would need to actually tunnel TCP over HTTP like in [this Activestate recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577643-transparent-http-tunnel-for-python-sockets-to-be-u/).